# Proguard does not find basic packages and super class

Tags: proguard

I used to use proguard 5 on java 8, but as I now use Java 11, I've downloaded proguard 6.1.1, but I've encountered issues.

1 - Lot of warnings are generated because proguard does not find basic classes present in `java.awt` or `java.lang`:

```
Warning: ...: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning: ...: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JPanel
Warning: ...: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
```

I can remove all the warning by adding a global or specifics `-dontwarn`, but I don't think it's ideal. Is there a better solution?

2 - If I remove the warnings, with the option `-dontwarn`, an error is generated:

```
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [...]
  Method      = [<init>()V]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [softwares/progeria/nuclei/NucleiLabeling] (with 1 known super classes) and [java/lang/InterruptedException] (with 4 known super classes))
Unexpected error while preverifying:
  Class       = [...]
  Method      = [<init>()V]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [...] (with 1 known super classes) and [java/lang/InterruptedException] (with 4 known super classes))
Error: Can't find common super class of [...] (with 1 known super classes) and [java/lang/InterruptedException] (with 4 known super classes)
```

The class that generates this error extends a JFrame and runs perfectly. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

Your application depends on various runtime libraries which you need to tell ProGuard about.

Prior to Java 8, all of the built-in java libraries such as `AWT`, `Swing` etc. were bundled together in `rt.jar`. You would have supplied something like the following parameter to ProGuard:

```
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
```

or if using Ant:

```
<libraryjar file="${java.home}/jre/lib/rt.jar" />
```

Since Java 9, these runtime libraries are packaged as a number of jmod files under `<java.home>/jmods`. As a minimum you will probably need:

```
-libraryjars  <java.home>/jmods/java.base.jmod(!**.jar;!module-info.class)
```

or if using Ant:

```
<libraryjar file="${java.home}/jmods/java.base.jmod(!**.jar;!module-info.class)" />
```

However this will not include AWT or Swing, which are now in `java.desktop.jmod`. Precisely which of the jmods you need to link will depend on which Java runtime libraries your application makes use of.

In your case it looks like you need

```
-libraryjars  <java.home>/jmods/java.base.jmod(!**.jar;!module-info.class)
-libraryjars  <java.home>/jmods/java.destop.jmod(!**.jar;!module-info.class)
-libraryjars  <java.home>/jmods/java.management.jmod(!**.jar;!module-info.class)
```

or

```
<libraryjar file="${java.home}/jmods/java.base.jmod" jarfilter="!**.jar" filter="!module-info.class" />
<libraryjar file="${java.home}/jmods/java.desktop.jmod" jarfilter="!**.jar" filter="!module-info.class" />
<libraryjar file="${java.home}/jmods/java.management.jmod" jarfilter="!**.jar" filter="!module-info.class" />
```

A web search for `jmod <some class or package>` or simply `JDK Module Summary` should help you identify any others you might need.

Note: If there is no <java.home>/jmods folder, and you use openjdk please note that there's a separate package for it search for java-11-openjdk-jmods to install the right package

Comment: > please note that there's a separate package for it search for java-11-openjdk-jmods
Lifesaver, thank you! Bummer it's 300mb though.